# Python3 x64 unicode ok, ARMv7 not

Tags: python-3.x, arm

When trying to print a test:

```
print(áéíóú);
```

In my x64 computer works fine, but on my ARM7 server which also has Python 3 i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("\xe1\xe9\xedo\xfa")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm puzzled. This last error was supposed to happen on Python 2.x as the strings are by default encoded in ASCII, but on 3 they are by default UNICODE. Any tips?

Comment: Did you mean `print("áéíóú")` or similar?  The line in the tracement is different yet, with unaccented 'o'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your server has an ascii-only screen.  Check by separating input and output on differnet lines and see which line raises.

```
s = "\xe1\xe9\xedo\xfa"
print(s)
```

Comment: This it is likely that `sys.stdout.encoding` is one that cannot handle those characters.  What is it for you?

Comment: Sorry Terry, did not understand your question :P

Comment: What is result of `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: So my suspicion was correct.  The is the canonical name for 'us-ascii'.